# Dynamically changing Label variable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

What I am trying to do is build a window with a number(default value=1) and
3 buttons underneath it named: "UP","DOWN" and "QUIT". "Up" button is going to increment the number by 1 and the rest of the buttons are clear what they do.

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
number=1
Label(root,text=number,height=10,width=7).grid(row=0,pady=10,padx=10,column=10,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)

def auksisi(number):
    number+=1
    return number
def meiosi(number):
    number = number -1
    return number
Label(root, text=auksisi(number),height=10,width=7).grid(row=0,pady=10,padx=10,column=10,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)
Button(root, text="up",command=lambda: auksisi(number)).grid(row=3,column=2,columnspan=2)
Button(root, text="down",command=lambda: meiosi(number)).grid(row=3,column=3,columnspan=2)
Button(root, text="quit",command=root.destroy).grid(row=3,column=4,columnspan=2)

root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

What is happening is when I press the buttons nothing changes.Don't worry about the layout I will fix it, I just want the buttons to work.

Comment: `auksisi` and `meiosi` don't actually update the `Label`, what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: how can I update the label?

Comment: As it stands, you can't, because you don't retain a reference to the `Label` instance. Alternatively, I think you could use an `IntVar` instead of a vanilla `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grid` method returns `None`, and calling it directly after the creation of your objects, would make your *eventual* references to be `None` as well. To change the values of your label, you need a reference to it:

```
label_reference = Label(root, text=auksisi(number), height=10, width=7)
label_reference.grid(row=0, pady=10, padx=10, column=10, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)
```

Now, through `label_reference` you can change the text using for example the `config()` method. You can do this in the method that is called when you click your buttons:

```
def auksisi(number):
    number += 1
    label_reference.config(text=number)
    return number
```